# Sort alphabetically, add rows, calculate and add texts...is it possible?

Tags: excel, vba

First and foremost thanks for taking the time to read this thread.
Secondly, I would like to know if there is anyone who could kindly help me to build a VBA with different functions.

I have a sheet with columns from A to L, containing text and numbers. The amount of row will not be the same every day.

I would like to create a macro that:

1. organizes the data on Column D alphabetically,
2. then adds a new row for every unique text
3. sums the data on both columns E and F and display the result on the row right below
4. then merge Column G and H and add the text "pay" on it.

Here is the visual example of the excel sheet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkd03.png)

Here is the outcome i would like to achieve
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5APn.png)

Have tried finding solutions to my "problem, but no luck!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions tagged with `excel-vba` **without** any code attempts and where it's going wrong will most likely be closed. SO is not a script writing service. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can be achieved with a Pivot table without re-inventing the wheel with VBA.

Comment: Hi teylyn, thank you so much for the advice and my apologies for misinterpreting this forum rules. Have a nice day, Raphael